# Impose binary constraint on integer matrix with CVXPY

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, python, cvxpy

So I have the following matrix:

\begin{equation}
P_{i,j}=
  \begin{bmatrix}
  x_0 & x_1 & x_2 \\
  y_0 & y_1 & y_2 \\
  z_0 & z_1 & z_2 
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

where each of the elements in the matrix are binary variables (can be either 0 or 1). I am solving an optimization problem where I want to impose a constraint where each of the rows of the matrix have to have $n$ number of zeros. So for example, for the first row of matrix $P$ (containing the $x_i$ elements), I want to enfore that for this row, I want **one** of these $x_i$'s to be zero (but not explicitly stating which one should be zero). As a second example, for the second row of matrix $P$ (containing the $y_i$ elements), I want to enfore that for this row, I want **two** of these $y_i$'s to be zero (but not explicitly stating which ones should be zero). And so fourth...

Is there a way to make this kind of formulation?
I was thinking of imposing the constraints as follows:

$\sum_j P_{1,j} = 2$

$\sum_j P_{2,j} = 1$

Would this be the correct approach?

Your help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `boolean=True` for the matrix variable `P`, and use the constraints you have proposed.